# Optimize this ArrayList join method

Tags: java

I have written this code to join ArrayList elements:
Can it be optimized more? Or is there a better different way doing this?

```
public static String join(ArrayList list, char delim) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (i != 0)
                buf.append(delim);
            buf.append((String) list.get(i));
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.java.html) is how the famous java.util.Collection team are doing it, so I'd assume this should be pretty good ;)

```
  421       /* Returns a string representation of this collection.  The string
  422        * representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
  423        * order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets
  424        * (<tt>"[]"</tt>).  Adjacent elements are separated by the characters
  425        * <tt>", "</tt> (comma and space).  Elements are converted to strings as
  426        * by {@link String#valueOf(Object)}.
  427        *
  428        * @return a string representation of this collection
  429        */
  430       public String toString() {
  431           Iterator<E> i = iterator();
  432           if (! i.hasNext())
  433               return "[]";
  434   
  435           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  436           sb.append('[');
  437           for (;;) {
  438               E e = i.next();
  439               sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
  440               if (! i.hasNext())
  441                   return sb.append(']').toString();
  442               sb.append(", ");
  443           }
```

Also, this is how you'll get comma delimiters with duffymo's answer ;)

Comment: No, my answer is far easier than this.  See below.

Comment: mmmm - I've spent too much time reading the core Java source to say that the algorithms there must be good.  There is some optimization work done, but on something like a toString() method, which will never be used in a high throughput, production system, code is written for clarity, not speed.  For example, in the above code, they have an if statement in the loop. It would be faster to always append the comma, and then modify the SB at the end to get rid of the extra one.

Comment: @duffymo: What I meant is, since this is the implementation of toString() in your answer, Pentium 10 can see why it will produce a String with comma delimiters.

Comment: @Kevin Day: Haha, might be, but this comes from the Collection guys and they supposedly are good. One of the author of this class is Josh Bloch himself. I agree that your suggestion will be probably faster though.

Answer (score 2):

StringBuffer is synchronized for thread safety, use a StringBuilder instead.

Don't call list.size() each iteration of the loop. Either set it as a variable or use an Iterator.

Also note that there are lot of libraries for doing this, chiefly [google collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html).  Try the following:

```
public String join(List<?> list, char delimiter) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (Iterator<?> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        result.append(i.next());
        if (i.hasNext()) {
            result.append(delimiter);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: result is a local variable, so thread safety shouldn't matter.  The only issue related to concurrency here is the possibility that the list is modified while it's iterating.

Comment: @sidereal: It's just that StringBuilder is faster because it has no synchronization. While I guess recent JVM will optimize away the unnecessary synchronized keyword anyways...

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a method at all?  Why not just use the toString() method for List?

```
public static String join(List<String> list) 
{ 
    return list.toString(); // comma delimiter with some extra stuff at start and end
}
```

You can do better than the method you wrote.  Add the List interface and generics; maybe even Collection.  It'll be more generic and type safe; no casts needed.

Run this class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ListToStringDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> values = Arrays.asList(args);
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

with any string arguments on the command line (e.g., "foo bar baz bat") and get this output:

```
C:\JDKs\jdk1.6.0_13\bin\java  ListToStringDemo foo bar baz bat
[foo, bar, baz, bat]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I don't understand how will this get the comma delimiters?

Comment: commas come along for the ride - the toString() method handles this for you.  I actually really like this approach - not because it's faster (you do wind up with extra brackets around it), but because it doesn't involve much code (and therefore has less things that can go wrong).  Props to duffymo, even though he's not getting much upvote action.

Answer (score 1):

Is this known known for sure to be causing some performance problem or are you doing this as an exercise? If not, I wouldn't bother.

I *suppose* this could be faster, but I doubt it:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    buf.append((String) list.get(i));
    buf.append(delim);
}
buf.append((String) list.get(i));
return buf.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that [Google Collection](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)'s [Joiner](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class would be a useful place to start.  Specifically, the `public final String join(Iterable<?> parts)` method.

Answer (score 1):

#### #1

You're checking the size of the list each time your loop iterates:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
```

Since you're not altering the list, you only need to do this once:

```
for (int i = 0, j = list.size(); i < j; i++) {
```

#### #2

Instead of checking for `i != 0` in each iteration, just append a delimiter after each iteration:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        buf.append((String) list.get(i));
        buf.append(delim);
    }

    // Here, convert all but the last character in the buffer to a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Better, maybe:

> List instead of ArrayList

Program for interfaces not implementations

> for (String string : strings) instead of for (int i ... )

foreach loops from 1.5 are actually more efficient according to Josh, and far easier to grok

etc etc as others have noted

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it could be significantly *optimized* (meaning getting faster) without getting arcane.  However, it can be *improved* by using generics.

```
public static String join(List<String> list, char delim) {
   StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(512);
   first = true;
   for (String item : list) {
      if (first) {
         first = false;
      } else {
         buf.append(delim);
      }
      buf.append(item);
   }
}
```

Improvements in this version: you're enforcing that the item contains only strings at the compiler level, you don't have to maintain a loop variable, and you're not requiring an ArrayList, which is an implementation detail your API shouldn't enforce.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers you have received, you can pre-initialize the capacity of the `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`. This reduces the number of times that the internal array must be recopied as it is expanded. Since you do not know the exact capacity needed you can make an estimate of the average size of each element and multiple by the number of elements.

```
private static final int ESTIMATE_ELEM_SIZE = 8;

public static String join(Collection col, char delim)
{
    int len = col.size();
    if (len == 0)
        return "";
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(ESTIMATE_ELEM_SIZE * len);
    for (Object elem : col)
    {
        buf.append(elem).append(delim);
    }
    return buf.substring(0, buf.length() - 1);
}
```

This shows some techniques others have shared: use `StringBuilder`, do not put `if` check within loop, and use foreach enhanced loop.

I would also recommend changing the first parameter to the most generic type that makes sense so it is more reusable. In this case, since you really do not need indexes to address each element, this can specify a `Collection`.

Note there is also no need to cast to `String` since `StringBuilder.append()` will convert the element to a `String` if necessary. This allows you to use this with collections containing other kinds of objects other than strings.