# What's the quickest way to output the list<String> as space seperated list

Tags: java

```
List<String> test
```

which contains several items,

what would be the quickest way to output a string as "item1 item2 item3"?

Comment: *"what's the quickest way to.."* Ask random strangers to do it for you?  Oh wait, you've already got that covered.

Comment: Furthermore, what do you mean by "quickest". Performance, shortest amount of code perhaps?

Comment: Lot of possible dupes here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+%2Bstring+%2Bjoin This one has several good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389448/optimize-this-arraylist-join-method Just benchmark them each and post the results in a blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) included in your project,

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on(' ').join(myList));
```

Comment: I'm happy to see someone suggesting Guava.  These kinds of boilerplate utility nonsense should not be written anymore.  Also saves you from writing test cases on as that's the Guava developer's problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "quickest in terms of debugging".
If it's a `List<String> itemList`

```
for (String item : itemList) {
    System.out.print(item + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Your mistake here is that there will be a trailing space at the end of the list.

Comment: I took it as "quick and dirty" I guess =)

Answer (score 1):

Helper function that leverages string builder for efficiency and allows passing any delimiter.

```
public String join(List list, String delim)
{ 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String str : list)
    {
       sb.append(str + delim);
    }
    sb.delete(sb.length() - delim.length(), sb.length());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(stringsList);
```

You just need to do this, comma and space seperated strings will be printed on console, quickest is ambiguous term though.